# Decorator with parameters injection

Tags: python

I would like to injecte a decorator on a method class from another class.

I have the following interface :

```
class Interface(object):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta


    @abc.abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        """Run the process."""
        return
```

I am have my class that uses the interface

```
class Launch(Interface):

    def run(self):
        pass
```

What I would like to do is inject decorators (that have arguments) from within my **Interface** class into my **Launch** class.

I have tried to use [Decorator injector](http://yloiseau.dnsalias.net/hacks/DecoratorInjection/decoratorinjection#examples) but without success.

What would be the best way to implement such a feature ?

Comment: What specifically fails when you _"try to use Decorator injector but without success"_?

Comment: I just cannot figure out how to implement the trick.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do, and the link is broken (or the site is down) -- is there another link, or can you explain further what your goal is?  A concrete example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your help I create the follwing function that detects if implementation is done :

```
  modpath = "C:/mypath"

            for modname in listdir(modpath):
                if modname.endswith(".py"):
                    # look only in the modpath directory when importing
                    oldpath, path[:] = path[:], [modpath]
                    if not modname[:-3]=="__init__":
                        module=__import__(modname[:-3])
                        if  not module.__dict__.has_key("ProcessInterface") :
                                print module.__name__
```